# Как в MSVC поместить конструкцию do-while внутри тернарного оператора?

Tags: c++

В clang++ и g++ следующий код успешно [компилируется](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h66fPdaEo)

```
(true) ? ({do{int a = 0;}while(false);}) : void(0);
```

Но в visual studio [не компилируется](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xTf7dq9Pf).

Пробовал убирать скобки, ничего не меняется.

> Подобный код используется в макросе, где при истине выполняется один
> кусочек кода, в противном случае - другой.

```
#define MI_ASSERT(arg) !(arg) ? MI_CRASH() : MI_NOTHING()

// for clang & GCC
#define MI_CRASH() ({do{/*crash this code*/}while(false);})

// for msvc
#define MI_CRASH() // ...
```

Я, конечно, могу поменять код на обычный `if`, но мне больно интересно знать, как все-таки правильно записать эту конструкцию, чтобы все успешно скомпилировалось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта конструкция не является валидной в стандартном С++. И приведенный код [не компилируется ни в gcc, ни в clang](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEINIADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/qRJKY4CIWGRLDFx0naYDmlCBEzEBBk%2BfgEVVQI1dQSFEdGx8ba19Y1ZLYNdoT0lfZIAlLaoXsTI7BwmGgCCoQQA1CxMoRAzJgDsVhvbF9sQBMRemDPbJgDMAGJXJxboqB9b20yPTwAItsNM8rMdAQB3BB0TDUMRKI5PcGAh4gbYAN1QeHQEA0SIsjw2J0BHDmtE4AFZeH4OFpSKhOG5rNZtgoFktMI8zE8eKQCJoyXMANYgJ5PAB04ulMtlADZ9JxJDTBQzOLwFCANPzBXM4LAYIgUKgWAlYWQKBA0KbzSBgFwuAEaLQCLFNRAoqqoqE6gBPTh861sQQAeQYtH9dN4WD2RnEUdI%2BGIlUcGMwmoTmFUlS8roDvC2mApCdoeCixD9HiwqpueBY%2BbmVAMwAUADU8JhISGEox8zJBCIxOwpP35Eo1KrdFx9IZjCzLPoy5rIHNUAl8gwMwBaLcKAjoZ6A0yWaxcY7bLcAdR76EMjmQF8vsWIJA1RZTaRcDHcniaemCEzFKUei5KkAjDH406gRu3RAX006tBuHRDL%2BWQIe%2BbQMMh4xFL0cQIWMEF6HunSwXhEhzOyizLHoNyYCsPDklSKoJoyHCqAAHHKW5ypI2zAMgD4OhKZhXMyJ4LtsuCECQ3K8qQ2weDa9DEHJXAzLwApRjMIogJS2rFsqpD1vppC0vSbEalqOraaQ%2BpGgsBAJLm5CUNaZoqf%2B%2BBEPho6DuII78IIigqOoCZ0QxvCQhWCQNoqHDUmZqpsSGubOTsqBUNsnHcbx/GCdswmiRASkebEakaTZWg6aQCCYEwWBxIc8VGSZ2rmbwlm2NZWnVbp4pSrKQ3igqxZPCxFnqlVZJ2Ya9kQEg7nmq5VommVcTIAYRhcE8Gjas6rrEO6noJt6zDEJGgYmsGBBhhGqoxrO8b0kmH5phm9JZjmebcAWghFqqpblpWGArPStb1r9jbNm2HZdj2tJ8kFwiiAF0jIyFE4JroARbXOEk2EDy7NWuG7bru%2B6HseViWGej43neeAPlez6vrYGEbl%2BP6ZJBgTfmRUy%2BdBaREVByRgQwAvAeh9hIYRqG84h1RjFL8EDJ0ovq/Uqv4ZRHI0dOEVxcWiUdWq7FcTxfGbbOhWShoEoaGJ842FJ3myeY8mKWt5pyWYlW9UKpCigNw3DS1vBtUlrFTZq2qB3qc1II56UrUtnkBJg7u%2Bcj/nDujsiY2F4PJpFpDRUwsVQ/FpvJZwqVObm2yZdllt5TbRh247jtiT7Kl%2BwHupzHVDV9M1hmR3p7V1xwVnx0PwdipKYdDfF43R5Ns/TTVxZmBNnVTQncxpkdn6SEAA%3D).

Comment: В GCC не компилируется из-за добавленных флагов. Вообще без флагов компилируется нормально.

Answer (score 0):

В visual studio это невозможно.